# Tax Question for US Citizen moving abroad

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

I am an American Citizen moving to Argentina and will continue to work for my US based company.  Should I be paid offshore to establish the foreign earned income exclusion or it does not matter?

Comment: You may find http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ useful.

Comment: @AaronDufour doubt it.

Comment: @littleadv Why do you doubt it? Is the expats site less likely to have money questions (and answers)? Is it not part of their mandate? A little info here would be nice.

Comment: @jeffreypriebe no-one there with the expertise to answer. I had to correct people there on at least several occasions when they wrote things horribly wrong.

Comment: Not sure what status you are looking to achieve in Argentina but you should be aware that as a resident you will be taxed on your worldwide income.

Answer (score 10):

As a general US income tax rule (e.g. [**§861(a)(3)**](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/862#a_3)), if the payment is due to services actually performed in another country, then the location of the bank or branch taking your salary is [**not going to be relevant**](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Foreign-Earned-Income-Exclusion-Can-I-Claim-the-Exclusion-or-Deduction).  Go ahead and take your compensation in the US, if that is convenient for you.

This is particularly important for working in a country with the [**economic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998%E2%80%932002_Argentine_great_depression), [**political**](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/falklands-argentina-mocks-britains-promise-2985994), and [**legal**](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/the_americas/seizure-of-repsol-affiliate-in-argentina-stuns-oil-markets/2012/04/25/gIQANkHrhT_story.html) instability of Argentina, which has had no shortage of [**banking**](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-04-21/argentina-gets-skepticism-at-u-s-high-court-on-bank-subpoenas.html) and [**currency**](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB123111629554952657) issues.  So most of your assets, including your direct deposit, can be held in non-Argentine accounts if that is more convenient for you.